# React-natives AsyncStorage does not work

Tags: android, react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to call a function that includes AsyncStorage-calls (receives and stores data to 'TutorialNotOver'). My program worked while ago but somehow it got broken. React-Native does not give me any warnings or errors, it just don't work right. Looks like the program just skips the call of GetfirstTime()-function.

```
<View>
...
{this.props.firstTime = this.GetfirstTime}
...
</View>

...

async GetfirstTime(){
    let firstTime = "null";

    try{
        firstTime = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TutorialNotOver', (err, result) => {
            console.log("GetfirstTimeFirstTime: " + result);
        });
    }
    catch (error){
      console.log(error);
    }

    if (firstTime === 'null')
    {
      firstTime = 'true';
    }


    if (firstTime === "true")
    {
      try{
       AsyncStorage.setItem('TutorialNotOver', "true");
       return true;
     }
     catch (error){
       console.log(error);
     }
   }
   return false;

}
```

Comment: I added () to end of the this.GetfirstTime. Now React-Native gives me an error: "Object are not valid as React child (found: object with keys {_45, _81, _65, _54})."

Comment: I did put `{this.props.firstTime = this.GetfirstTime}` in `render()`-function but when I moved it to `componentWillMount()`-function, it works now.